# How would python recognise if a string is in the right format? (LLNN.LLL)

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a program that would check if the letters and numbers in a string are in the right order, and the example I am using to write it is a car registration plate. Is it possible to check if the letters and numbers in a string correspond to a format of where they are in relation to each other?

For example:
The user inputs a car's registration, and the program checks if it is a standard number plate or not, and if it isn't, the program tells the user. The format's allowed would be from a standard UK registration plate (LLNN.LLL), and the strings could be up to 10 characters long.

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info ...?!

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Have you tried writing any code to do it? Or even have some ideas of how to approach it?

Comment: You must further specify which formats are allowed and how long your string is etc. But in general you need a regular expression.

Comment: I tried, but couldn't find any ways to do it. I am fairly new to python, and so don't have much experience with it.

Comment: I am not familiar with UK licence plates. How can it follow the format `LLNN.LLL` _and_ be up to ten characters long?

Comment: I think he includes the braces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

For example number plates in my country are 3 letters and 3 numbers (ABC-123) so the regex string would be `([a-zA-Z]{3})-([0-9]{3})`

You can use http://pythex.org/ to test regex patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I try to give an answer but it is likely that this is not what you want:

```
import re
string1 = "(LLNN.LLL)"
string2 = "(abcdefgh)"
reg = re.compile(r'\([LN]{4}\.[LN]{3}')
print bool(re.match(reg, string1))
print bool(re.match(reg, string2))
```

This matches all the strings that consist of (, 4 times L or N, a dot and 3 times L or N.

Comment: `L` and `N` are supposed to mean "letter" and "number" respectively, not _literal_ `L` and `N`. You should change those to `[A-Z]` and `[0-9]`.

Comment: Ok, then this is not the solution he wants. But I don't have the time to find out how UK registration plates look like ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this code takes the registration something like xjk649 and tests it, and prints when its false:

```
iReg = input('Registration:  ')
test = ''
for i in range(0,len(iReg)-3):
    if 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.find(iReg[i]) != -1:
        print('succes first three charracters')
    else:
        test = 'WRONG'


for j in range(3,len(iReg)):
    if '0123456789'.find(iReg[j]) != -1:
        print('succes last three charracters')

    else:
        test = 'WRONG'

if test == 'WRONG':
    print('false resgistration')
```

hope this helped

Thanks